# How to save an image with more than 3 channels using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, alpha, channel

I need to save a tiff image with 4 channels, specifically R,G,B and A channels.

When I try using `Image.save()` to save a tiff with 4 channels, the resulting image is an RGBA image but when examining the tiff in Photoshop the only channels are RGB, without the Alpha. Is there any way to merge 4 channels to a RGBA image, with a 4th channel (a separate alpha channel)?

Below is an example of what I've tried

```
from PIL import Image

# import image A
inputImageA = Image.open(input_imageA_path)

# import image B
inputImageB = Image.open(input_imageB_path)

# split channels
R, G, B, A = inputImageA.split()
alpha_channel = inputImageA.split()[-1]

# merge 4 channels back into a single image
outputImage = Image.merge("RGBA", [R,G,B,alpha_channel])

# save the new image
outputImage.save(ouput_image_path)
```

In this example the resulting output image only has 3 channels (RGB).

Please see below image for a visual explanation of what I'm trying to do:

[image: example]

Comment: Please, self answer, not put your answer in the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer**

Ok, I think you mean this now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Open background image, ensuring RGB
im = Image.open('start.png').convert('RGB')

# Open alpha channel, ensuring single channel
alpha = Image.open('alpha.png').convert('L')

# Add that alpha channel to background image
im.putalpha(alpha)

# Save as TIFF
im.save('result.tif')
```

Which makes `start.png`:

[image]

plus `alpha.png`:

[image]

into `result.tif`:

[image]

**Original Answer**

Here's a simple example of creating and saving a 4 channel, RGBA TIFF:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Create RGB image full of yellow
w, h = 640, 480
im =Image.new('RGB',(w,h),color=(255,255,0))

# Create alpha channel of white i.e. opaque
alpha =Image.new('L',(w,h),color=255)

# Get drawing context to draw into alpha channel and draw black (i.e. transparent) rectangle
d = ImageDraw.Draw(alpha)
d.rectangle([10,40,200,250],fill=0)

# Add that alpha channel to yellow image
im.putalpha(alpha)

# Save as TIFF
im.save('result.tif')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mark! Thanks for the reply but that isn't exactly what I'm looking for. Maybe I wasn't very clear so please see the following image for a more visual explanation of what I'm trying to do.

https://i.imgur.com/7bvuzJJ.png

Comment: Ok, sorry, I had another attempt!

Comment: No problem! Thanks again for the quick response. Still not exactly what I'm looking for though. What I'm looking for is for the RBG channels in the final image to not be effect at all in the resulting image. Rather, I want the alpha channel simply added to the resulting image as a new channel, similar to clicking "Create new channel" in photoshop for the RBG image, then simply pasting the alpha channel to the new channel created. I'm not even sure if this is possible with PIL but I hope this clears things up a bit more!

Comment: So you want a 4-channel TIFF where the 4th channel isn't alpha! If so, look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/53778125/2836621 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53780571/2836621

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thanks, I will check out those links

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution to this issue using the OpenCV2 library instead of PIL. See below how I did it:

```
import cv2

# read original image
original = cv2.imread(original_image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# get dimensions for resizing mask
height, width, channels = original.shape

# read alpha image
alpha = cv2.imread(alpha_path)

# resize alpha image to match original
alpha_resized = cv2.resize(alpha, (height,width))

# split alpha_resized into individual channels
channels = cv2.split(alpha_resized)

# apply to 4th channel of original
original[:,:,3] = channels[0]

# write new image file with alpha channel
cv2.imwrite(output_path,original)
```