# How can I convert a numpy array to grayscale format without changing the array intensities?

Tags: python

I have a numpy array of size `(512,512)` with maximum intensity of 3071 and minimum intensity of -1024. I want to preserve the intensity while converting it to (512,512,1).
I tried
`Image.Open(fromarray().convert('L'))` but it converts the intensities to 0 and 255.

Please guide me what can be the best way to achieve the above goal. Original data is grayscale.

Comment: Exactly what grayscale image *format* are you trying to convert to?

Comment: so you're just trying to add a dimension shape wise?
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html

Comment: not an expert here tried to answer compressing your 4095 range into 8bit grayscale 0 to 255 then realized you want to keep your min max values. Can use 16bit grayscale image but keeping your range everithing will look black upon img.show(). as per creating your image mode in pillow think we need big guns

Comment: you could create an array from o to 65535 (16bit) populated only by your 4095 different values and fill a 16bit array representing your pic with those values but I think that won't answer your problem:  scale = np.linspace(0,65535, 4095).astype(int) then replace values in your array with values from scale

Comment: try to search for 12bit image mode see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63310083/dynamic-range-bit-depth-in-pils-fromarray-function

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
img = Image.fromarray(arr.astype(np.uint16) * 2**4)
```

explanation somehow here:

[Dynamic range (bit depth) in PIL's fromarray() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63310083/dynamic-range-bit-depth-in-pils-fromarray-function)